# How to plot a 3D vector field

Tags: python, matplotlib, vector, matplotlib-3d

Is there a way to plot a 3D vector field in matplotlib? I have seen [quiver](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.quiver), but it only talks about a "2-D vector field of arrows". Is there a 3D counterpart somewhere?

LMGTFY:
I figured a documentation for the 3D counterpart would be returned by this search term:

```
"3-D vector field of arrows" matplotlib
```

But it returns zero results

Comment: mayavi can plot 3D vector field: http://github.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/mlab.html#id1

Answer (score 31):

As of matplotlib 1.4.x, quiver can now plot in 3d.

[quiver3d_demo.py in the examples directory](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#quiver):

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

x, y, z = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.2),
                      np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.2),
                      np.arange(-0.8, 1, 0.8))

u = np.sin(np.pi * x) * np.cos(np.pi * y) * np.cos(np.pi * z)
v = -np.cos(np.pi * x) * np.sin(np.pi * y) * np.cos(np.pi * z)
w = (np.sqrt(2.0 / 3.0) * np.cos(np.pi * x) * np.cos(np.pi * y) *
     np.sin(np.pi * z))

ax.quiver(x, y, z, u, v, w, length=0.1)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: why are the x,y,z coordinates in a 3D array??? I don't understand how to read them. And how to input my own? Any help is great thanks

Comment: The points don't have to be a 3D array.  You could just create/load your own 1D position arrays x, y, z, and corresponding velocities u, v, w.  The call to quiver would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.  3D plotting in matplotlib is fairly new and this is all there is to it so far: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/index.html

Maybe ask the matplotlib mailing list if vector plots are being developed.